# Is it possible to update the backend configuration automatically during the deploy?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, deployment, backend

The configuration of [cron jobs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) is updated automatically as part of the deploy. As long as my app contains a cron.xml file, GAE will update the configuration automatically as part of the deploy. I expected changes in the [backends.xml file](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview) are treated in the same way.

Do I have to run the

```
 appcfg backends <dir> update backend_name
```

command every time manually after the deploy in order to update the backends configuration? Or can I re-configure the deploy so that the backends configuration is updated automatically?

**EDIT:** After [reading the docs on resident vs. dynamic backend instances](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends#Types_of_Backends) again it seems to be very clear. For resident backend instances the startup is: *Manual, via the Admin Console or command-line tool*. For dynamic instances the startup happens *Upon receipt of an HTTP request*. If I read this correctly there is no notion of restarting/reconfiguring backends on deploy.

Comment: Are you deploying your app with appcfg?

Comment: I am deploying with mvn gae:deploy using Kindle IT's maven plugin. After that I am running appcfg to force and update of the backend configuration. I am looking for a way to update everything at once: the application code + all the configuration (cron.xml, queue.xml, backends.xml, etc).

Comment: Just for completeness: The Google Plugin for Eclipse allows to deploy frontends & backends in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

I believe backend development should be separated into another folder and must be uploaded using appcfg backends command.

Think it this way, backend can have it's own appengine-web.xml config file to specify how request are handled and which files are static resources etc... It's pretty obvious that backend can contain totally different code from front end.

Just don't mix backends and frontends files together. Treat them like different App is what I do